# Printing line by line using a for loop then scanning to another in c

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

In the array below i have 11 questions stored. I want each question to be asked one by one and then the answer copied to arrray ans1. Currently the while loop prints the whole file off at the same time. Can someone shed light on how i can use the for loop below the while loop to complete this?

```
  typedef struct{
  char q[40][250];
  char a[40][250];
  } qa;

  int main()
  {   

     char *b [40][250];
     int w, e, r, t, k, l;
     char a1[40][250];

     FILE *fp;
     fp = fopen("quest.txt", "r");

     while (fgets(b, sizeof(b), fp)) {
           printf("%s", b);
           scanf("%s",a1[1+]);
     }

     for(l>=0;l<=40;l++){
     ;}
```

Comment: Check return value of input function calls `scanf()`.

Comment: A good compiler should shout warnings or even errors at you with that code. The [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) function expects a pointer to the first element of an array of *characters* as the first argument, not a pointer to an *array* of characters.

Comment: Furthermore, what is the initial value of `e`? Hint: You *don't know*, because it's *indeterminate* (and seemingly random). Therefore using it as an array index will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which makes any discussion or guessing about behavior useless.

Comment: Please upgrade to a [mcve].

Comment: Lastly, what is the range of valid indexes of an array of e.g. `40` elements? The top index is *not* `40`. Which makes the loop condition in the second loop wrong, if you're supposed to use `l` as an index into any of your arrays. Note that the initialization of `l` is, well, not initializing anything. Perhaps you should get a few beginners books, and start over from the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues like uninitialized variables (e.g. `e`, `l`),  reading in into a wrong data structure (`fgets(b,...` instead of `fgets(b[x],...`).

See the following code fragment which probably helps you a step further.
Note that I used `fgets` for reading in the answer; this allows you - in contrast to `scanf("%s")`-  to enter more than one word as an answer (i.e. until you press "enter"):

Hope it helps.

```
 char b [40][250];
 char a1[40][250];

 FILE *fp;
 fp = fopen("quest.txt", "r");

int nrOfQuestions = 0;
while (nrOfQuestions < 40 && fgets(b[nrOfQuestions], sizeof(b[0]), fp)) {
    printf("%s", b[nrOfQuestions]);
    fgets(a1[nrOfQuestions],sizeof(b[0]), stdin);
    nrOfQuestions++;
}

for (int i=0;  i<nrOfQuestions; i++) {
    printf("q:%s a:%s\n", b[i], a1[i]);
}
```